# setter c# shows error make sure you do not have an infinite loop or infinite recursion

Tags: c#, getter-setter

this is the topic connection for [get user input in form 2 and display data in form 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11791071/get-user-input-in-form2-and-display-data-in-form1-in-c-sharp).

This is my code in form2.

```
public string UserText
    {
        get 
        { 
            return this.textBox1.Text; 
        }
        set 
        {
            this.UserText = value;
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        if (textBox1.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter keyword to search");
        }
        else 
        {
            //anta data input to form1.
            UserText = textBox1.Text;
        }
```

and this is my code in form1

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 form2 = new Form2();
        form2.ShowDialog();

        string text = form2.UserText;
    }
```

i want when we click on button search, it will automatically display the data when we load the form1.

when i run, it says at the setter:

> make sure you do not have an infinite loop or infinite recursion.

why it says that?what did i do wrong?

i also had tried did.

```
public string UserText
    {
        get 
        { 
            return this.UserText; 
        }
        set 
        {
            this.UserText = value;
        }
    }
```

but it appears the same.

====EDIT====
now im trying to use this:

```
public string UserText
{
    get 
    { 
        return this.textBox1.Text; 
    }
    set 
    {
        this.textBox1.Text = value;
    }
}
```

also i tried this:

```
public string UserText { get; set;}
```

it does not show the error however, it also does not load the form1. the operation just stops there. is there anything i have done it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using C# 4

```
public string UserText {get;set;}
```

you have to put the Form2 in the Form1 Constructor

```
    public Form1()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

    Form2 form2 = new Form2();
    form2.ShowDialog();

    string text = form2.UserText;
    }
```

this will happend before the Form1 is shown

Comment: it the same with my comment above. it does not show the error but why when i click the button1, it does not appear form1?what should i add to make it load the form1 too?

Answer (score 3):

The code in your setter for the `UserText` property: `this.UserText = value;` calls itself.  Based on the getter, I think you should make the setter be like this:

```
set
{
    this.textBox1.Text = value;
}
```

Comment: ok. it does not show the error but why when i click the button1, it does not appear form1?what should i add to make it load the form1 too?

Comment: Adding this property, and making it public will only expose it so that in your button5_Click method, after you call form2.ShowDialog(), you can access form2.UserText, and it will contain the value that you entered in the textbox in form2.

Comment: It would be a really good idea to change your names from `button1`, `button5`, `form1`, and `form2` to names that accurately describe the functionality of the control.

Comment: did u mean by this: public void searchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)? it still does not work.

Comment: im accepting because it does not appear the error. only it does not load the form. i think my mistake is just minor which i may not noticing it. that is what i thought.